# elastic search query result sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below query which is resulting in correct data. But looking to have sorting done, means have exact match first then rest.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Han* Ol*",     
      "fields": [
        "firstName",
        "lastName",
        "customerNo"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
      "analyze_wildcard":true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to have exact match on top then others like -
Hanry Oliver,
M Hanry Oliver,
Hanry Tran Oliver

Answer (score 0):

The term "exact matches" in the context of wildcard queries is ambiguous, if not meaningless. But if I understand you correctly, you could [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boosting) the "exact matches" [through a `phrase_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-multi-field-parms) and by [adjusting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html#regexp-standard-operators) the query string to `(Han).* (Ol).*`:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(Han).* (Ol).*",
            "fields": [
              "firstName",
              "lastName",
              "customerNo"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and",
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Han* Ol*",
            "fields": [
              "firstName",
              "lastName",
              "customerNo"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```